# Bitcoin API - CloudFlare 403 Response

Tags: php, api, http-status-code-403, bitcoin, cloudflare

I am creating a php application with the Coinbase API and the blockchain.info API. My (000webhost.com) webhost's communications with coinbase.com and blockchain.info API servers are getting a HTTP 403 CloudFlare Captcha. This completely cripples the API. I tried connecting with HTTPS, and tried changing the user agent, tried curl(), tried file_get_contents(), but I can't seem to get a real response from the API servers.

This is the error I get:
http://s10.postimg.org/ff8ggm6yx/Cloud_Flare_error2.jpg

Thanks for any help, I've been trying to figure this out for days.

Comment: The image is really low in quality. Can you provide some example code?

Comment: You can see the at the bottom of the page about why are you getting this captcha. I think someone has used the IP address or subnet from that host to launch malicious attacks against Cloudflare protected properties. You probably want to have a discussion with your hosting company about getting a non-blacklisted IP address, or consider changing hosts to one where that isn't an issue.

Answer (score -1):

The captcha is a security challenge page presented based on the security settings selected by Coinbase. Either the IP you're using or the user agent you're sending triggered the security challenge page here. If you complete the captcha (in a browser) a cookie would be temporarily set indicating you've passed this security challenge page successfully. Your best bet would be to contact Coinbase's support folks if you are still seeing this issue, and request that they consider whitelisting your IP address so that in the future you wouldn't receive a security challenge page like the one you indicated.

Disclaimer: I work at CloudFlare.

Comment: It seems rather silly to block requests with a CAPTCHA which are intended to originate from machines and terminate with a service's API endpoint. Isn't there a way to deal with this?

Comment: The site was being attacked. Not silly at to server a security challenge CAPTCHA ..and the attacker (with the garbage traffic) won't be able to complete the CAPTCHA and their traffic will be discarded. Legit traffic would be capable of completing the CAPTCHA and gaining access to the site. In the case of an API and/or automated access we actually worked closely with the site owner just recently to ensure these kinds of security challenge CAPTCHAs won't need to be enabled on their API endpoint in the future, while still protecting them from attacks. This shouldn't be an issue any longer.